# Unknown command when using promise-ftp in node

Tags: node.js, promise, ftp

I'm trying to use a promise approach when interacting with my ftp server. I'm using the node package 'promise-ftp' v1.3.5.

The code I have is as follows:

```
const appFeedBuffer = Buffer.from('somedatastring', 'utf8');
var Client = require('promise-ftp');
var ftpClient = new Client();

ftpClient.connect({ host: 'myHost', user: 'me', password: 'mypassword' })
    .then(() => {
        return ftpClient.mkdir('newDir')
    }).then(() => {
        return ftpClient.put(appFeedBuffer, 'fileName')
    }).then(()=> {
        return ftpClient.rmdir('oldDir')
    }).then(() => {
        return ftpClient.rename('newDir', 'oldDir')
    }).then(() => {
        return ftpClient.end();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log("something went wrong: " + err);
        res.status(500).send('SERVER ERROR');
});
```

The problem is the `put` command - I get the error 'UNKNOWN COMMAND' which appears to come from the [@icetee/ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@icetee/ftp) library, of which promise-ftp is a dependant. `put` is most certainly a valid command in the [promise-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ftp) library!

Stack:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unknown command
at makeError (/Users/projects/ftpProject/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:1128:13)
at Parser.<anonymous> (/Users/projects/ftpProject/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:122:25)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Parser.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Parser._write (/Users/projects/ftpProject/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/parser.js:61:10)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:397:12)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:383:5)
at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
at Socket.ondata (/Users/projects/ftpProject/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:298:20)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

I can't find anyone else having this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also share the version of promise-ftp you're using ( check from node_modules)? Also please share the stack trace of the error.

Comment: Will update in the morning.

Comment: Updated with more info